# How to keep from populating textarea on a null value when user cancels the prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

This is part of a tool I am designing to make uniform, clear remarks when testing hi cap data circuits, What is an easy way without having to totally revamp my code to keep the following from populating the textarea on a null value when user cancels the prompt?I totally forgot about bull values when writing this... UGH!!!! I have tried a != "null" conditional and that keeps from populating the textarea completely.

```
<!-- Remarks Textarea Begin --><td><textarea
 id="REMARKSTEXTAREA" rows="10" cols="100">***CCSC***
      </textarea></td>
<!-- Remarks Textarea End -->

<!-- BEGIN ACCESS DROPDOWN MENU -->
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 638px;">
      <select id="accessdropdownmenu">
      <option value="">MAKE A SELECTION</option>
      <option value="1">ACCESSED CLLI @ XXX IN "A"
DIRECTION…</option>
      <option value="2">ACCESSEDCLLI @ XXX IN "Z"
DIRECTION…</option>
      <option value="3">ACCESSED CLLI @ XXX (FULLY
IMBEDDED) IN "A" DIRECTION…</option>
      <option value="4">ACCESSED CLLI @ XXX (FULLY
IMBEDDED) IN "Z" DIRECTION…</option>
      <option value=" GETTING IMMEDIATE AIS ALARM…">GETTING
IMMEDIATE AIS ALARM…</option>
      <option value=" GETTING IMMEDIATE RAI ALARM…">GETTING
IMMEDIATE RAI ALARM…</option>
      <option value="5">XXX MAPPED CORRECTLY TO XXX PER
CLR/DLR…</option>
      <option
 value=" CROSS CONNECTS DO NOT MATCH PER CLR/DLR INFO...">CROSS
CONNECTS DO NOT MATCH PER CLR/DLR INFO...</option>
      <option value=" NO DACS TEST POINTS PER CLR/DLR…">NO
DACS TEST POINTS PER CLR/DLR…</option>
      <option value=" NO REMOTE TEST ACCESS POINTS PER CLR/DLR…">NO
REMOTE TEST ACCESS POINTS PER CLR/DLR…</option>
      <option value="6">UNABLE TO ACCESS CLLI @ XXX...</option>
      </select>
      <script>
var mytextboxaccess = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
var mydropdownaccess = document.getElementById('accessdropdownmenu');
mydropdownaccess.onchange = function(){
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 1) {
var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE ARE YOU ACCESSING?");
var ACCESSPOINT = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT ARE YOU USING?");
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " ACCESSED " + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + " IN 'A' DIRECTION.."; this.value = "";}
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 2) {
var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE ARE YOU ACCESSING?"); var ACCESSPOINT = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT ARE YOU USING?");
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " ACCESSED " + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + " IN 'Z' DIRECTION.."; this.value = "";}
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 3) {
var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE ARE YOU ACCESSING?");
var ACCESSPOINT = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT ARE YOU USING?");
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " ACCESSED " + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + " (FULLY IMBEDDED) IN 'A' DIRECTION.."; this.value = "";}
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 4) {
var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE ARE YOU ACCESSING?");
var ACCESSPOINT = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT ARE YOU USING?");
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " ACCESSED " + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + " (FULLY IMBEDDED) IN 'Z' DIRECTION.."; this.value = "";}
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 5) {
var ACCESSPOINT1 = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT DID YOU ACCESS?");
var ACCESSPOINT2 = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT IS IT MAPPED TO?"); mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " " + ACCESSPOINT1 + " MAPPED CORRECTLY TO " + ACCESSPOINT2 + " PER CLR/DLR.."; this.value = "";}
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 6) {
var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE WERE YOU ATTEMPTING TO ACCESS?");
var ACCESSPOINT = prompt("WHAT ACCESS POINT WERE YOU USING?");
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + " UNABLE TO ACCESS " + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + ".."; this.value = "";}
else {
mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + mydropdownaccess.value + ".."; this.value = "";}
}
      </script>
      </td>
<!-- END ACCESS DROPDOWN MENU -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't comment, but you said you tried

```
if(CLLI != "null") {
   // do stuff
}
```

It should be:

```
if (CLLI !== null) {
  // do stuff 
}
```

An alternative way to approach this problem is to use [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operators.

One example might be

```
if (mydropdownaccess.value == 1) {
     var CLLI = prompt("WHAT CLLI CODE ARE YOU ACCESSING?");
     CLLI = (CLLI !== null) ? " ACCESSED " + CLLI : '';
     mytextboxaccess.value = mytextboxaccess.value + CLLI + " @ " + ACCESSPOINT + " (FULLY IMBEDDED) IN 'Z' DIRECTION.."; this.value = "";}
}
```

However, spending some time to refactor your code probably will be to your benefit.